# Dynatree how to change url for children ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

How can I change Url for ajax response for children?

E.g. I have

```
onLazyRead: function (node) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://google.com"
            ...
})
```

and load any children. I want by clicking on children click also load by ajax, but from another action, not from "http://google.com". How can I change it for children nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `url` (or whatever you want) property to your child nodes and use as

```
onLazyRead: function (node) {
          $.ajax({
            url: node.data.url
            ...
})
```

Comment: >> you can add url (or whatever you want) property to your child nodes

But how? I can't find it in documentation

Comment: I only found that there is "node.data.key" option and I can make response from server accordingly with node's key

Comment: to be more clear, you can use `node.data` property for this. and on your onLazyRead, use it as `url: node.data.url`

Comment: Ok. And node.data.url - parameter from server? I can't find supported option url. Is it custom? sorry, i'm newbie

Comment: Yes, it is custom. on documentation, it states "Use this attribute to access all node options that were passed to create this node.
For example `node.data.title` or `node.data.tooltip`." (You can pass url as option)